# ValueError: x is required to have ndim 1 but has ndim 2 | ARIMA model and plot_pacf

Tags: python, arima

I loaded in data of Bitcoin and tried to plot it into a PACF graph. But it returned this error (`x` is my dataframe variable):

```
ValueError: x is required to have ndim 1 but has ndim 2
```

I also get this error when I attempt to fit the model with `x`. The only way around it is to only give it one column (`x.Close`). But I want to train the model with all the features. How do I do that?

Full Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot as acf_plot
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_pacf
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
import datetime

x = pd.read_csv('BTC-USD.csv', header=0, parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=0)
x.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(x.index).to_period('D')
x = x.sort_index()

"""
plot_pacf(x)
plt.show()
"""


model = ARIMA(x, order=(12, 0, 0))
model_fit = model.fit()
print(model_fit.summary())

output = model_fit.forecast()

print(output[0])
```

Comment: each feature is a time series you can plot them one by one

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense. Thank you!